# Geoserver source code: Where do the methods in classProperties.java come from

Tags: geoserver, java

I try to understand the geoserver source code and therefore play around with it. For my task I want to find out where I can find the "methods" stated in the code below from the ClassProperties.java class in the org.geoserver.ows.util package. When printing the methods.getname() out I get this response:

List item 
indexOf 
indexOf 
isFrozen 
getMap 
map 
getCapabilities 
getStyles    
getLegendGraphic 
capabilities

Although clazz.getMethods() gets these methods I can't find them in the code. where does Class clazz.getMethods() get them from?

ClassProperties.java

```
/* (c) 2014 Open Source Geospatial Foundation - all rights reserved
 * (c) 2001 - 2013 OpenPlans
 * This code is licensed under the GPL 2.0 license, available at the root
 * application directory.
 */
package org.geoserver.ows.util;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Provides lookup information about java bean properties in a class.
 * 
 * @author Justin Deoliveira, OpenGEO
 * @author Andrea Aime, OpenGEO
 *
 */
public class ClassProperties {
    private static final List<Method> EMPTY = new ArrayList<Method>(0);

    private static final Set<String> COMMON_DERIVED_PROPERTIES = new HashSet<>(
            Arrays.asList("prefixedName"));
    List<Method> methods;
    List<Method> getters;
    List<Method> setters;

    public ClassProperties(Class clazz) {
        methods = Arrays.asList(clazz.getMethods());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the class that's passed as a parameter to `ClassProperties(Class clazz)`.

Obviously depending on the class, you'll get different methods.

The usage is simple:

```
ClassProperties cp = new ClassProperties(String.class);
ClassProperties cp2 = new ClassProperties(cp.getClass());
```

The first one would access `String`'s methods, the second one would access the class' own methods.

If you can't see the class name in any way, the only way to find the class would be to search for all classes and check whether they have the same methods (not a very good idea).

Comment: When hovering over it it tells me this package: class org.geoserver.catalog.impl.StyleInfoImpl but I don't find a class named Class in it. How can this be? How would you try to find this class?

Comment: @Andrej `Class` is a class object. If you pass `String.class` as parameter, it will display the methods that `String` class has.

Comment: Ok but how did it get the methods then that i listed above? Somehow they must have been passed to it?

Comment: @Andrej Because somewhere there is `ClassProperties cp = new ClassProperties(SomeClass.class);` (or `someObject.getClass();`). You're not a Java developer, are you?